# How do I use arguments from the command line in an if statement?

Tags: if-statement, for-loop, command-line, go

I am brand new to programming, golang being my first language, and I am having some issues figuring out how to access variables from the command line. I am trying to take flags input in the command line by a user, and use those variables in an if statement. I want the for loop to run through all arguments input by the user, then compare each one in an if statement and see if any match up with specific flags. All println statements are for testing purposes. How would I correctly write this for loop/if statement?

```
var Args []string

for i := range os.Args {
    fmt.Println("array item", i, "is", os.Args[i])

    if i := os.Args("-target") {
        fmt.Println("GREAT SUCCESS")
        targetHostNew := targetHost
    }
}

fmt.Println("-------------------------", targetHostNew)
```

I should have clarified as well. The program needs to be able to read flag arguments input but not alter those arguments variables

Comment: Rewrite the loop as [`for _, arg := range os.Args {`](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#for) - does that clarify how to proceed? (The array index is "discarded" with `_` and the value of the argument to use is bound to `arg`; `os.Args` should *not* be used within the loop after this change.)

Comment: The answers are right about `flag`/`Args` and @user2864740 is right about how to use `for ... := range ... {` to iterate over an array. For all the variations look at the table in [the spec on "for"](http://golang.org/ref/spec#For_statements) with the Range expression/1st value/2nd value headers.

Answer (score 3):

You need to access the variables through `os.Args` after calling `flag.Parse()` or assign them to variables using the `flag` package.

Check out this example on both:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "flag"
)

func main() {
    // declare variable
    var targetHost string

    // tell flags to put cmd line (string) arg into variable
    flag.StringVar(&targetHost, "target", "defaultValue", "")

    // do the actual parsing of command line variables
    flag.Parse()

    // loop over all arguments by index and value
    for i, arg := range os.Args {
        // print index and value
        fmt.Println("item", i, "is", arg)
    }

    // is targetHost defaultValue - then it wasn't set on the command line
    if targetHost == "defaultValue" {
        fmt.Println("target not set")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("target set to", targetHost);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `flag` package http://golang.org/pkg/flag/

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
)

var ip = flag.String("target", "localhost:3000", "help message for target")

func main() {
    flag.Parse()
    fmt.Println(*ip)
}
```